# How to use user_metadata from Auth0 on AWS Cognito PreSignUpTrigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, auth0

How can I use a custom attribute? For instance, I am trying to get the user_metadata from Auth0 into my user attributes in pre signup trigger,  I am putting in a lot of effort to map the **user_metadata** from **Auth0** into my **Cognito** **PreSignUpTrigger** user attributes, but unfortunately, I'm not succeeding :(

I've inserted these scopes:
[image]

I've mapped out the attributes as follows:
[image: attribute mapping print]

My Auth0's user raw JSON:

```
{
    "created_at": "2023-05-24T15:32:34.338Z",
    "email": "iago.cardial+ubi8@email.com",
    "email_verified": true,
    "identities": [
        {
            "connection": "Username-Password-Authentication",
            "provider": "auth0",
            "user_id": "646e2e12fb1f075041d4471a",
            "isSocial": false
        }
    ],
    "name": "iago.cardial+ubi8@email.com",
    "nickname": "iago.cardial+ubi8",
    "picture": "https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/567a3ff0854079542356ba66e82609a7?s=480&r=pg&d=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.auth0.com%2Favatars%2Fia.png",
    "updated_at": "2023-05-25T14:56:48.328Z",
    "user_id": "auth0|646e2e12fb1f075041d4471a",
    "user_metadata": {
        "companyBadgeNumber": "iago-ubi8",
        "companyId": "someId"
    },
    "app_metadata": {},
    "last_ip": "45.234.41.254",
    "last_login": "2023-05-25T14:56:48.327Z",
    "logins_count": 21,
    "blocked_for": [],
    "guardian_authenticators": []
}
```

And my PreSignUp Trigger Event Request into Cognito has only these fields:

```
{
    "version": "1",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "userPoolId": "us-east-1_xpto",
    "userName": "saml_auth0|someId",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
        "clientId": "someClientId"
    },
    "triggerSource": "PreSignUp_ExternalProvider",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "email_verified": "false",
            "cognito:email_alias": "",
            "cognito:phone_number_alias": "",
            "email": "iago.cardial+ubi8@email.com"
        },
        "validationData": {}
    },
    "response": {
        "autoConfirmUser": false,
        "autoVerifyEmail": false,
        "autoVerifyPhone": false
    }
}
```